# With the Dialogflow python SDK, when deleting entity types I sometimes get "400 Some entity names are in use" error

Tags: dialogflow-es

I use Dialogflow V2 API and python SDK. I am trying to delete entity types with batches, or just one by one using `EntityTypesClient`. I first delete all the intents, and then delete all the entities but most of the time i get this "entity name is in use" error for one of the entity types.

`google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Some entity names are in use`

Setting timeout to ~1000s seems to help but not always, however if I try it multiple times it deletes that entity on the second or third try.

What could be the reason for it?

Comment: Do you have an active session using the entity?  i.e. have you (or another user) queried your Dialogflow agent and utilized the entity in question in the last 30min? Session last 30min from the most recent query.  Any query from any integration (or through the API) will start a session and the session will say active for 30min after the most recent query.

Comment: Thank you @matthewayne , I believe i had active sessions during the deletions. Any way to close all the active sessions with the SDKs?

Comment: I have tried without any open sessions and still get error. If i delete entities from web console i don't, can it be an issue with the python SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has mostly 3 reasons:

1. the agent is still training, in which case you need to wait for it to finish training
2. you need to delete the relevant intents before the entities
3. for composite entities you need to observe the order of deletion, aka first delete the composition, then the parts

point 3 can be solved by batch deleting all entity types in one go